# How to remove all kind of non-breaking spaces with php

Tags: php, whitespace

I am saving a string from Html file into my database.
I fail to get the string trimmed and clean of whitespaces.

I created this simplified function to summarize the problem and what I've tried so far.

```
<?php

function get_content($html)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $div = $dom->getElementById('whitespace');
    $content = $div->textContent;
    # Goal:  trim leading, trailing, and non-breaking space
    $content = str_replace('&nbsp;','',$content);
    $content = str_replace('U+00A0','',$content);
    $content = str_replace('\u00a0','',$content);
    $content = str_replace('\xa0','',$content);
    $content = str_replace(chr(160),'',$content);

    $content = trim($content);
    return $content;
}

file_put_contents(
    'trim.output',
    get_content('<div id="whitespace">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; TuffToTrim</div>'
));
?>
```

The output is:

```
      TuffToTrim
```

While I'd like it to be:

```
TuffToTrim
```

I'm kind of desperate at this point :) Any ideas?

Comment: I think You only replace non-breaking spaces, but keep the normal spaces. Replace them by `$content = str_replace(' ','',$content);`

Comment: Maybe to convert it first: $content = htmlentities($content, null, 'utf-8');
$content = str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $content);

Comment: `$div->textContent` is doing something strange with the `&nbsp;` there. When you paste the text directly into $content all is fine. I know this doesn't help yet - but it might give a hint where to search further.

Comment: @equi Thanks! That's the perfect solution. And I learned about htmlentities and htmlspecialchars.

Comment: @StoyanGeorgiev You're welcome. I'm glad it was helpful. I will post it as answer then, so it can help others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be converted to HTML entities first. Then you should be able to replace characters.

```
$content = htmlentities($content, null, 'utf-8'); 
$content = str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $content);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Instead of**

```
$content = str_replace('&nbsp;','',$content);
$content = str_replace('U+00A0','',$content);
$content = str_replace('\u00a0','',$content);
$content = str_replace('\xa0','',$content);
$content = str_replace(chr(160),'',$content);
$content = trim($content);
```

**You should use**

```
$content = preg_replace('/[\s]+/mu', '', $content);
```